# this.types.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, vuejs2

This filter function used to work until I did some changes within my site and now it's throwing this error.

I have an array of objects and would like to loop through them and return the correct name.

```
types = [{"name":1,"type":"Daily"},
        {"name":2,"type":"Bi-Weekly"},
        {"name":3,"type":"Monthly"},
        {"name":4,"type":"Yearly"},
        {"name":5,"type":"Other"}]
```

Function

```
getType(id) {
                return this.types.filter(e => e.name == id)[0].type
            }
```

Comment: Is it just `types`, or actually `this.types`? What does `console.log(types)` show?

Comment: I'm using VueJs, so to call it in the methods I need to use this.types - and the console log shows exactly what i've assigned to the types

Comment: Try using `find` instead - you're wanting to `find` the item which has a matching ID.

Comment: Just tried that and its giving me the same error except with 'find' is not a function.

Comment: Is `Array.isArray(this.types)` true?

Comment: No, it says false

Comment: Although when I console.log(this.types) I get it as an array of objects

Comment: Therefore `this.types` is not an array, which is why `find` and `filter` don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `types` in your component's `data`, `props`, or `computed`.  And define `getType` in `methods`

```
data: function() {
  return {
    types: [{"name":1,"type":"Daily"},
        {"name":2,"type":"Bi-Weekly"},
        {"name":3,"type":"Monthly"},
        {"name":4,"type":"Yearly"},
        {"name":5,"type":"Other"}]
  }
}
```

```
methods: {
    getType(id): {
                return this.types.filter(e => e.name == id)[0].type
    }
}
```

If they are defined outside of the component, and you don't need to call them from a Vue template, then **don't use `this` at all.**  In that case they will be at `global` or `module` scope.

Comment: This worked! Do you know why it didn't work when I try to set it as a variable?

Comment: Within a component, all templates implicitly call `this`, so it is not needed.  All script options need `this` to refer to the component.  My guess is you defined `types` outside of the component and tried to reference it with `this`.  I don't see your complete example so it is hard to say...